how can I change my pc running Ubuntu 24.4 LTS from BIOS to UEFI without a rebuild
I appreciate that this question has been asked before but I don't see any that A) are exactly the same as my issue or B) are not way over my head.
Quite simply I am running Ubuntu 24.4 LTS and have a lot of stuff on it which I would rather not have to re-install.
I have suddenly started getting an error advising "attempt to read or write outside of disk "hd0"  Entering rescue mode"
From what I have seen here and in other places on the web this appears to be caused by the fact that I'm running BIOS rather than UEFI.
My question is: Can someone tell me how to convert from BIOS to UEFI in simple terms that even I can understand please?

First you really should have a good backup. Then you can reinstall system, restore /home, reinstall apps from saved list and perhaps some other settings. With a bit of pratice, you can restore in an hour or less. Most other options are more complex. Do you have gpt or MBR(msdos) partitioning. Post these from live installer if you cannot boot. sudo parted -l and lsblk -f You may be able just to convert install by reinstalling grub. Grub uses grub-pc for BIOS and grub-efi-amd64 for UEFI. But gpt requires and ESP - efi system partition FAT32 with boot, esp flags.

How large is drive? http://gparted.org/h2-fix-msdos-pt.php#partition-outside-disk

Thanks for the responses, I'm running a 2Tb drive with a 512Mb FAT32 partition.  I have GParted installed and it shows the partition as fat32 /boot/efi and the remainder as extended  1.82TiB.  Given that from what I've read on-line "attempt to read or write outside of disk "hd0" error is supposed to be a problem with a BIOS drive only, I'm well confused.

Having tried to restart several times with no joy and booted it from a memory stick successfully and shut down I then found that it restarted ok.  but later when I shut it down it won't start again.  I have noticed that it is not displaying the error message any more, its just going to a flashing cursor.  I've tried changing the boot source in the BIOS settings but it doesn't make any difference.

As the saying goes " To be confused is human but to be completely baffeled you need a computer".  Because the error message seemed to be changing all the time, I decided to disconnect all drives except for the main boot drive and the pc booted fine.  I reconnected one drive at a time, checking that it booted.  Now all drives are connected and the pc is ok.  I conclude that the BIOS or UEFI got confused and that by removing all the possible sources of confusion it settled back on the correct setting.  My thanks to those who offered advice, its always helpful to get other opinnions.  Cheers
